# rosdep update: "No address associated with hostname"

Tags: ros, rosdep, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Intel RealSense robotic development kit.  I installed Ubuntu 16.04.

```
$ which rosdep
/usr/bin/rosdep
$ rosdep --version
0.11.5
$ apt-cache policy python-rosdep
python-rosdep:
  Installed: 0.11.5-1
  Candidate: 0.11.5-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.11.5-1 500
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.11.4-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

so version is not the problem.  I'm able to ping raw.githubusercontent.com and get results

```
$ ping raw.githubusercontent.comPING raw.githubusercontent.com (151.101.48.133) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from raw.githubusercontent.com (151.101.48.133): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=74.5 ms
64 bytes from raw.githubusercontent.com (151.101.48.133): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=80.8 ms
64 bytes from raw.githubusercontent.com (151.101.48.133): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=24.8 ms
64 bytes from raw.githubusercontent.com (151.101.48.133): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=21.9 ms
^C
--- raw.githubusercontent.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.915/50.552/80.889/27.279 ms
```

However, when I get to installing rosdep, I get this:

```
$ sudo apt -y install ros-kinetic-desktop-full python-rosinstall ros-kinetic-realsense-camera
[sudo] password for <>: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-rosinstall is already the newest version (0.7.8-1).
ros-kinetic-desktop-full is already the newest version (1.3.0-0xenial-20161211-213832-0800).
ros-kinetic-realsense-camera is already the newest version (1.6.1-0xenial-20161204-170602-0800).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ sudo rosdep init
Wrote /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Recommended: please run

    rosdep update
$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml]:
    <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml]:
    <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml]:
    <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml]:
    <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml]:
    Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
    <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
ERROR: error loading sources list:
    <urlopen error <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml)>
```

I have no proxy on my Internet connection, either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253225/rosdep-update:-%22no-address-associated-with-hostname%22/) by [ad8700](https://answers.ros.org/users/29195/ad8700/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-29**:
What is the output of `getent hosts raw.githubusercontent.com`?

**Comment by [ad8700](https://answers.ros.org/users/29195/ad8700/) on 2017-01-29**:
151.101.48.133  raw.githubusercontent.com

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-30**:
And

```
python -c "import urllib2; resp=urllib2.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml', timeout=15.0); print resp.info()"
```

also returns successfully?

Note that Github is known to be unstable and experiences lots of transient network errors.

**Comment by [ad8700](https://answers.ros.org/users/29195/ad8700/) on 2017-01-31**:
No, it also fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. That would perhaps point to a problem with how Python resolves addresses.

Two things I would try / test:

1. try some other hostnames / URLs
2. create a Wireshark capture of the traffic when you run the above one-liner

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0